# Address Textarea Element Won't Autofill in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am updating a web form that looks like this:

[image]

My goal is to make it so that each of these fields autofills using information stored in the user's browser's address book.

I don't have direct access to the HTML, but I can add JavaScript to the page. I have added this jQuery:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id$='WizDonationForm']").attr("autocomplete", "on");
    $("[id$='DdlTitle']").attr("autocomplete", "honorific-prefix");
    $("[id$='TbFirstName']").attr("autocomplete", "given-name");
    $("[id$='TbLastName']").attr("autocomplete", "family-name");
    $("[id$='DdlCountry']").attr("autocomplete", "country-name");
    $("[id$='TbAddress']").attr("type", "autocomplete");
    $("[id$='TbAddress']").attr("autocompletesearch", "addrbook");
    $("[id$='TbAddress']").attr("autocomplete", "billing street-address address-line1");
    $("[id$='TbCity']").attr("autocomplete", "locality");
    $("[id$='DdlState']").attr("autocomplete", "region");
    $("[id$='TbZip']").attr("autocomplete", "postal-code");
    $("[id$='TbPhone']").attr("autocomplete", "tel-national");
    $("[id$='TbEmail']").attr("autocomplete", "email");
  });
</script>
```

This does what I want in Chrome, Edge, and Opera, but in Firefox, the textarea address field fails to autofill. This is the source code for the textarea address element after the jQuery is executed:

```
<textarea name="PC3650$ctl00$WizDonationForm$TbAddress" rows="3" cols="20" id="PC3650_ctl00_WizDonationForm_TbAddress" class="form-control" onblur="ValidatorValidate(document.getElementById('RfvAddress'));" type="autocomplete" autocompletesearch="addrbook" autocomplete="billing street-address address-line1"></textarea>
```

Why won't Firefox autofill this field from my address book? All other fields (other than title, see below) are autofilling as desired. I'm sure it must have to do with being a textarea rather than an input or select element, but I'm at a loss as to how to make it work correctly for Firefox.

An incidental but less important question is whether there is any way to make the title/honorific-prefix dropdown work. It currently works in no browsers, and it seems like no browsers allow you to store a title/honorific-prefix in your address book. So I'm guessing it can't be done, but I'd be interested in ways to make this work if anyone knows of any.

Comment: Was my answer below helpful? Did you learn anything else?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug that was never resolved.

[There are no fields for titles - honorific name prefix and suffix - in the address book cards](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=256247)

[Address book should have full vCard 4.0 RFC 6350 and RFC2426 (vCard 3.0) support](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29106)